# jQuery validate before ajaxForm

Tags: jquery, validation, ajaxform

I am trying to use the "beforeSubmit" option in the jQuery ajaxForm plugin to validate the data, however the form will submit even if there are invalid form fields. Where have I gone wrong? thanks,

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
function validator(){ 
        $("#commentForm").validate();
}

    $('#commentForm').ajaxForm({ 
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "http://highlandfamilyeyecare.com/contactengine.php",
        beforeSubmit:  validator,
        success:        function(data) { 
            $('ul.form').fadeOut("slow");
            $('ul.form').html(data.formula).slideDown('slow');}
    });
});
```

And the html:

```
<ul class="form">


    <li>    
        <form method="post" action="form.php" id="commentForm">

        <label class="white">Your Name</label>
        <input class="text-input required" type="text" name="name" /></li>

    <li>
        <label class="white">Email</label>
        <input class="text-input required email" type="text" name="email"/></li>

    <li>
        <li><input type='submit' value="Submit" />
        </form></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `beforeSubmit()` function isn't returning anything.

You'll want:

```
function validator() { 
  return $("#commentForm").validate();
}
```

presuming that the `$('#commentForm").validate()` exists and returns true/false correctly.

Comment: thanks, This worked when I added ".form" to the end of the function.
*********
function validator(){ return $("#commentForm").validate().form; }

Answer (score 3):

Per the [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object), the validating function must return `false` in order to prevent form submission.

Comment: +1 for rtfm. still needed to know why validate was not returning a false message

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `validate()` method is the validation plugin, This is the right way of doing it. If there are any errors in the validate method, form will not be submitted.

```
    $('#commentForm').validate({
        errorClass: "invalidField",
        submitHandler: function() {
            $('#commentForm').ajaxSubmit(ajaxFormOptions);
        }
    });
```

where `ajaxFormOptions` are your options for submit.

Comment: Just remember to add submitHandler: function(form) { $(form).ajaxSubmit etc.